# Combine lines in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL database I have several users with several groups. So now with my current query I have the problem that my query show:

[image: Actual query result]

Is there any way to get the query result like:

[image: Desired result]

I've already tried 'group_concat' but my sql server don't know that command.

Comment: You probably want to use `STRING_AGG()`

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: The version is SQL server 2014

Comment: What is your current query? Please post the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Using XML might be a possible solution, especially if you cannot use `STRING_AGG()` yet.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [ID],
    [user],
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [group]
           FROM [MyTable]
           WHERE [ID] = T.[ID] AND [user] = T.[user]
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS [groups]
FROM
    [MyTable] AS T
```

The subquery converts the groups to an "XML"-resultstring (well, just plain text in this case). Each separate group is prepended with a separator (`', '`), which is 2 chars long in this case. The first separator should be removed from the end result, which is done using the `STUFF` function.

Answer (score 0):

`group_concat()` is specific to MySQL, so you can't use it in SQL Server.

Starting with SQL Server 2017, using [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, this can be possible:

```
SELECT ID, [User], STRING_AGG ([group], ', ') AS [group]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID, [User]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link below when you have some free time.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

You will learn a lot from that resource.

```
SELECT *
FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Products]
```

[image]

```
SELECT CategoryId,
           MAX( CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END ) + ', ' +
           MAX( CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END ) + ', ' +
           MAX( CASE seq WHEN 3 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END ) + ', ' +
           MAX( CASE seq WHEN 4 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END )
      FROM ( SELECT p1.CategoryId, p1.ProductName,
                    ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM NORTHWND.dbo.Products p2
                        WHERE p2.CategoryId = p1.CategoryId
                        AND p2.ProductName <= p1.ProductName )
             FROM NORTHWND.dbo.Products p1 ) D ( CategoryId, ProductName, seq )
     GROUP BY CategoryId ;
```

[image]