# How to combine lines in sql query with two inner joins?

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL Server 2014 I have 3 tables. In one table is user information, in the other group information and in the third one are the dependencies of the users and the groups.

I've just set up my query but the result is not that what I want to be.
Like my recent question [Combine lines in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579853/combine-lines-in-sql-query) I want to try to get the similar result

[image: Result from my query]

Here is the query from my server:

```
SELECT server01.customer05.user.id, server01.customer05.user.namename, server01.customer05.groups.name FROM server01.customer05.username

INNER JOIN customer05.bgrel ON server01.customer05.id=server01.customer05.bgrel.username_id
INNER JOIN customer05.groups ON customer05.groups.id=customer05.bgrel.groups_id

WHERE server01.customer05.username != 'ANONYMOUS' and server01.customer05.username != 'INST_ROOT' and server01.customer05.username != 'SERVER_ROOT_3'

ORDER BY username
```

Comment: The version SQL Server 2014 v. 12.0.6024.0

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver ? In modern SQLS (2017+) we have STRING_AGG function to create CSV lists in a grouping query - if you can upgrade you should consider it, In older SQLS we have to fudge it - some techniques can be found at that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL Server Stuff-

```
WITH CTE (ID, [user],[ group])
AS
(
    SELECT 1,'max', 'g1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'max', 'Admin' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'Tom', 'g2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'Jan', 'g1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'Jan', 'K1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'Jan', 'O1'

    -- Above, you need to replace SELECT statements
    -- with your SELECT statement from which you are 
    -- Getting the first table output 
)
SELECT DISTINCT B.ID,B.[user],
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + A.[ group] FROM CTE A WHERE A.ID = B.ID FOR XML     PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') [Group]  
FROM CTE B
```

Output is-

```
ID  user    Group
1   max     Admin,g1
2   Tom     g2
3   Jan     g1,K1,O1
```

Comment: Unless a user can belong to the same group twice, you dont need the distinct in the stuff part

Comment: @GuidoG Yes, I considered duplicate group assigned for a user. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 1):

You can group your table by `ID` and `user`, and then use the `STUFF` function to get the `group` as comma seperated values

first lets build a test table that matches the sample data from your question.

```
declare @t table (ID int, [user] varchar(10), [group] varchar(10))
insert into @t (ID, [user], [group])
values (1, 'max', 'g1'),
       (1, 'max', 'admin'),
       (2, 'tom', 'g2'),
       (3, 'jan', 'g1'),
       (3, 'jan', 'k1'),
       (3, 'jan', 'o1')
```

now we can query the distinct ID's and users like this

```
select t.ID,
       t.[user]
from   @t t
group by t.ID, t.[user]
```

and that will give us

```
ID  user    
1   max     
2   Tom     
3   Jan
```

Now all we need is to get the group as comma separated value for each row, and that we can accomplish with the stuff function.

```
select t.ID,
       t.[user],
       stuff( (select ',' + t2.[group] from @t t2 where t2.ID = t.ID for XML path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') as [group]  
from   @t t
group by t.ID, t.[user]
```

the result will be

```
ID  user    group
1   max     Admin,g1
2   Tom     g2
3   Jan     g1,K1,O1
```

Looking at your query, I think you can implement it like this. I cannot not test that off course since I dont have your database.

```
select t.ID,
       t.[user],
       stuff( (select ',' + t2.[group] from @t t2 where t2.ID = t.ID for XML path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') as [group]  
from   ( SELECT server01.customer05.user.id, 
                server01.customer05.user.namename as [user], 
                server01.customer05.groups.name as [group] 
         FROM   server01.customer05.username
           INNER JOIN customer05.bgrel ON server01.customer05.id=server01.customer05.bgrel.username_id
           INNER JOIN customer05.groups ON customer05.groups.id=customer05.bgrel.groups_id
         WHERE  server01.customer05.username != 'ANONYMOUS' 
         and    server01.customer05.username != 'INST_ROOT' 
         and    server01.customer05.username != 'SERVER_ROOT_3'
       ) t  
group by t.ID, t.[user]
```

Comment: This should be the acccepted answer because it makes effort to educate rather than just give a soltuion